# Check stdin input not as individual entries

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I'm giving a while statement two conditions but it doesn't appear to be working as I want it to.

```
cout << "Enter S if you booked a single room or D for a double room and press enter." << endl;
cin >> rtype;
while(rtype !='S' && rtype !='D')
{
    cout << "That is not a valid room type, please try again." << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin >> rtype;
}
```

If I input `"Sfbav"`, it takes the input as valid because the first character is `'S'` and ignores that there are other characters there that would make it an invalid input.

How can I change this so that the input has to only be `'S'` or `'D'` to be treated as correct?

Comment: Is rtype a String ?

Comment: @AmitKumar It looks like it is a `char`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 yeah , but the op was trying to read 'Sfbav' into a char, so i thought it would be better to clarify.

Comment: Is your `rtype` a `char`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Option 1

Read the token as a string and compare it to `"S"` and `"D"`.

```
std::string rtype;
cin >> rtype;
while(rtype != "S" && rtype != "D" )
{
   cout << "That is not a valid room type, please try again." << endl;
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
   cin >> rtype;
}
```

#### Option 2

Read the entire line as a string and compare it to `"S"` and `"D"`.

```
std::string rtype;
getline(cin, rtype);
while(rtype != "S" && rtype != "D" )
{
   cout << "That is not a valid room type, please try again." << endl;
   getline(cin, rtype);
}
```

Comment: Seems mostly valid, wont the getline one fail to pass the newline though and print your cout message twice?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox, `std::getline` returns the string sans the newline character.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, works like a charm! I´m finding that the same thing happens when I ask for a number and put a number first but any other character after. Is there a similar way to fix that too?

Comment: @AlejandroGoicochea, use `getline` to get a line. Use `std::istringstream` to pull the number out. After that, try to get a character from the `istringstream`. If you are able to get a character, then you can reject that line.

Comment: How can I check that I got a character? I´m just starting with c++, don´t really know how istringstream works.

Comment: @AlejandroGoicochea, `char c; str >> c; if ( str ) { /* Got a character */ }`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the whole line, and check how many characters it has. If it has more than 1, then you know that the user entered `Sfbav` or something else.

```
while (true) {
    std::string line; // stores the whole input that the user entered
    std::getline(std::cin, line); // get the whole input
    if (line.size() != 1) // if it does not have exactly 1 character, than it is invalid
        std::cout << "That is not a valid room type, please try again.\n";
    else { // if it has only 1 character, everything is ok
        rtype = line.front();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use `if (line.size() != 1)` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why? Isn't it guaranteed that `std::getline` reads at least 1 character?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Never mind, it can return 0 characters if the stream contains only 1 new line. Thanks :)

Comment: The user could type just Enter by itself without typing any other characters at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think that will trigger it though. It never does for me. Well, after `std::cin`, `std::getline` can indeed read nothing because of the trailing newline left in the stream.

Comment: I just tested it, and `std::getline(std::cin, ...)` does return on Enter, even if there is no previous input in the stream.  As well it should be, since the purpose of `std::getline()` is to read a line, and pressing Enter produces a valid line, even a blank one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, you're right. Now it does it for me too. Ignore my comments then :)

Answer (score 0):

> if your `rtype` is `char`

In this case I prefer to use `std::setw( 1 )` to avoid getting more than one char, like:

```
char rtype;
std::cin >> std::setw( 1 ) >> rtype;  // Sabc
std::cout << rtype << '\n';           // S
```

and:

`#include <iomanip>`

Comment: This does not solve his issue: "If I input "Sfbav", it takes the input as valid because the first character is 'S' and ignores that there are other characters there that would make it an invalid input." You are still ignoring any other characters that would make it an invalid input.

Comment: @user2296177 For invalid characters your are right, but the question is not clear and I mention this as good-code for `char` type but he/she still should use `cin.ignore`. Anyways thanks you